# How to apply tooltip to option tag which already exists for the parent select tag in JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am working on an application where there are several select tags. I know how to apply tooltip on option tag but it will take a lot of time. Is there a way i can allot the tooltip allotted to select tag to be allotted to the below option tags?

```
<select tittle="Select Box" multiple="true">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option></select>
```

Comment: Try this type of tool-tip, This link may help you : http://www.sanwebcorner.com/2015/04/form-help-tip-on-mouse-hover.html

Comment: @user7357089 I cannot replace the tooltip as it is being used at several places other than select tag. If i replace it i will to test at each occurrence of help tip which will take more time.

Comment: Is there a way i can force select tag tootip to appear when hovering on option tag?

Comment: Can you please provide your existing tooltip how you are using it.

Comment: @user7357089 I have function which loads the tooltip. It is working fine the problem is when i hover on the select box the tooltip is displaying but as soon as i move inside the the select area to select the option tooltip disappears which i don't want. I want it to display even when i am hovering on the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the title to a div and add select inside that div without title.

```
<div tittle="Select Box">
    <select multiple="true">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option></select></div>
```